# Android studio does not print in new thread

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to debug a database process but Android studio does not seem to print statements in the new thread to the console. For example

```
            System.out.println("About to start new thread"); //this gets printed to the console

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    ContactsDatabase db = ContactsDatabase.getContactsDatabase(getApplicationContext());
                    db.contactDao().insertAll(contact);
                    db.close();
                    System.out.println("Inside new thread"); //this doesn't get printed, why not?


                }
            });
```

I am completely stuck. Am i doing something really stupid?

Comment: Have you considered using android.util.Log instead? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.start()` at the end

```
System.out.println("About to start new thread"); //this gets printed to the console
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside new thread"); //this doesn't get printed, why not?
            }
        }).start();
```